# Pull value from dataframe based on date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame below:

```
   userid   recorddate
0    tom    2018-06-12
1   nick    2019-06-01
2    tom    2018-02-12
3   nick    2019-06-02
```

How would I go about determining and pulling the value for the earliest recorddate for each user. i.e. 2018-02-12 for tom and 2019-06-01 for nick?

In addition, what if I added a parameter such as the earliest recorddate that is greater than 2019-01-01?

Comment: do you want pyspark solution or will pandas suffice? in other words, how big is your data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything will be easier if you convert your date strings into datetime objects.  Once that's done you can sort them then take the first record per userid.  Additionally you can filter the dataframe by passing a date string in your conditional, and proceed the same way.

```
df['recorddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recorddate'])
df.sort_values(by='recorddate', inplace=True)
df.groupby('userid').first()
```

output

```
       recorddate
userid
nick   2019-06-01
tom    2018-02-12
```

or

```
df[df['recorddate']>'2019-01-01'].groupby('userid').first()
```

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution with `loc`

```
df['recorddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recorddate'])
date = pd.to_datetime("2019-01-01")
df.loc[df['recorddate']>date]
```

Output will be:

```
    userid  recorddate
1   nick    2019-06-01
3   nick    2019-06-02
```

you can change the greater sign with equal or smaller sign to get a different result.
Cheers